# CodeIgniter - sorting CSV

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I have a table in my DB with following headers: `user, category, title, marks`
And values in it are like this

```
User1 - Food - Pizza - 19
User2 - Drinks - Cola - 18
User2 - Food - Spaghetti - 19
User1 - Food - Potato - 15
User1 - Drinks- Pepsi- 10
User2 - Food - Onion - 11
User1 - Food - Tomato - 10
```

This is also the way it printed in my CSV file, But what I'm trying to achieve in my CSV file is this format

```
     A(user)        B(=category)        C              D               E
1.  User 1         Food              Pizza -19     Potato - 15     Tomato - 10
2.                 Drinks            Pepsi
3. Empty row
4. User 2          Food              Spaghetti-19   Onion-11
5.                 Drinks            Cola-18      
6. Empty Row
7. A third user with his category's
```

This basically what I'm trying to achieve - Sorting the user then sorting the category's that the user has and then at every category the user has print the titles and the scores. But How can I sort and do logic for putting in a CSV?

I have the following code

**Model**:

```
function CSV(){     
    $this->load->dbutil(); 
    $this->db->select('user, category, title, score');
    $query = $this->db->get('Table_restaurant_scores');
    return $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, ";", "\r\n");
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function exporting(){
    $this->load->model('restaurant_mdl');
        $this->load->helper('download');
    $name = 'restaurant_scores.csv';
    $data = $this->restaurant_mdl->CSV();
    force_download($name, $data);
}
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you fetch your data in your model. You need to add order_by statement in your query e.g

```
$this->db->order_by("user", "asc");
$this->db->order_by("category", "asc"); 

// Produces: ORDER BY user DESC, category ASC
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. When adding the `order_by` It will sort it alphabetically and that is all... SO if have user1 5 times in my table, it will print it will print user1 5 times with his category's (and if he has more than 1 title in 1 category, that category will also be printed more than one time)